panda dataframe read excel formula not calculated result
I have defined a python function to read a specific range of an excel data table (list object) and convert it to a panda dataframe. Now, my problem is that I want the panda data frame read excel cell calculated result (value) not cell formula. But as the attached pictures shows it behaves against my expectation.(for example, if I have written a formula in cell T188 like: =MID([@name],3,10) which its result is "957" the panda dataframe read =MID([@name],3,10) not "957")Code Result
Can you guide me on this issue?
Additional information:
the code is
def excel_table(src_file):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    import pandas as pd
    from pathlib import Path
    # Initial_row=int(input("which row to begine?"))
    Initial_row=130
   

    wb = load_workbook(filename = src_file)

    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    # print(sheet.tables.keys())
    lookup_table = sheet.tables['Table1']
    print(lookup_table.ref)
    # Access the data in the table range
    data = sheet[lookup_table.ref]
    rows_list = []
    for row in data:
        # Get a list of all columns in each row
        cols = []
        for col in row:
            cols.append(col.value)
        rows_list.append(cols)
    # Create a pandas dataframe from the rows_list.
    # The first row is the column names
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list[Initial_row:], index=None, columns=rows_list[0])
    return df
df=excel_table(r"C:\Users\Trust.computer\Desktop\web scraping\sabad\constumers.xlsx")
print("df is")
print( df)

